# Am I able to reuse a HttpWebRequest?

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest

Am I able to reuse a HttpWebRequest?

It seems like the 3rd request to a site causes a operation to time out. It seems like each request creates a new connection, so I want to know if I can reuse a HttpWebRequest by changing the url and getting the request again. The code in question is below. This code checks if a range of urls exists.

```
    static void storeList(TextWriter sw, string urlTemplate, int start, int end)
    {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            var url = string.Format(urlTemplate, i);
            var req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            {
                req.Method = "HEAD";
                tryHttpWebRequest
                {
                    var resp = req.GetResponse();
                    sw.WriteLine(i);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        }
        sw.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: You are not reusing your `HttpWebRequest` in your example code - you make a new one each time around the `for` loop.

Comment: I know, thus the question, how do i reuse? ;)

Comment: Ah, ok. I though you were trying to show that you were reusing the request but it was not working.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be ok if you just call Close on your response. You are only allowed so many "open" connections, so the reason it is failing is because it can't open a new connection.

Once you are done with the response, you need to close it... no need to reuse anything.

From the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx):

> You must call either the Stream.Close
>   or the HttpWebResponse.Close method to
>   close the response and release the
>   connection for reuse. It is not
>   necessary to call both Stream.Close
>   and HttpWebResponse.Close, but doing
>   so does not cause an error.

Comment: @acid & josh - the implication of this post is that if the Response returned from (Begin)GetResponse can be closed and the request can be reused but tests do not support this. If you could post some code to clarify exactly what question you are answering would be great.

Comment: Nice. But - just theoretically - would it be possible to re-use a HttpWebRequest with another URL? As far as I see, both the Address and the RequestUri are read-only...

Comment: @pholpar - The underlying mechanics of how `WebReqest` work make this an implementation detail you don't have to worry about. `WebRequest` is managing the sockets for you, and will re-use a connection if certain conditions are met. You can read about those conditions in the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6

Comment: @Josh - Thanks for the response. It's nice to know, that the framework manages that things, but to tell the true, I have not worried about that at all. I was simply too lazy to define just another variable (and find a new name) for my WebRequest, and thought it might be possible to re-use an existing object, although I found no solution for that.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap your response call in a using statement to ensure that the connection is always closed:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
// ...
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
  // ...
}
```

Also wrap any GetResponseStream() in a using statement.

Comment: IIRC response doesnt have IDispose. I tried that before posting the question. Solution was to use .close at the end of each loop

Comment: @acidzombie24, `HttpWebResponse : WebResponse : IDisposable`, [and has done since .NET 1.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new one. I wouldn't worry about being efficient in this scenario, as the .NET environment + HTTP keepalives should handle things for you from that perspective I believe.

Probably you're running into either 1) an issue with the number of open connections; kill the connection and the error will go away or 2) an issue with limits of number of requests per second on the server (anti-DoS stuff). I'd try #1 first, as it's simpler, and then if you still see the problem, check to see if the server is getting the request but denying it.

Comment: A less-trivial reason for perhaps wanting to reuse an `HttpWebRequest` is that it seems a natural locus for configuration settings and session state since they inherently already need to be stored and/or accumulated there. Besides perpetual configuration busywork on each new request, the 'true' cross-request persisted state mostly consists of cookies going back and forth. I guess the idea of the .NET design of ephemeral request/response was that the `System.Web.CookieContainer` would be a lighter-weight way to quickly maintain, share, and attach cookies long-term for the duration of a session.