# VB.Net BeginGetResponse "The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly."

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous

Testing the throughput of different methods of sending web requests, so I created a class WebRequester that sends requests asynchronously using BeginGetResponse and implements the callbacks for BeginGetResponse and BeginRead.  When sending multiple requests in a loop from my calling code, if I reuse the same HttpWebRequest object I receive the following exception:

> "The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly."

If I create a new HttpWebRequest object during each iteration in my calling codes For loop, the exception never happens.

The problem is, creating a new HttpWebRequest on each iteration has a rather significant performance degradation.  What's going on here?

EDIT:  Forgot to mention some things.  Using Visual Studio 2017, .NET 4.5.2, Fiddler running on port 8888, and a NodeJS Express test server started on port 1337.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Test() Handles Button1.Click
        'Test using HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 2

        Dim iterations as integer = 1000
        Dim completedCount As Integer = 0
        Dim lock As New Object
        Dim mre As New ManualResetEvent(False)
        Dim wr As New WebRequester

        AddHandler wr.ResponseReceived, Sub(reqState As RequestState)
                                            SyncLock lock
                                                completedCount += 1
                                                If completedCount = iterations Then
                                                    mre.Set()
                                                End If
                                            End SyncLock
                                        End Sub

        'If I reuse the HttpWebRequest object below in my loop, I receive "The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly." :(
        'Dim req As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost.:1337/")
        'req.Proxy = New WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888)
        For i = 0 To iterations - 1
            Dim req As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost.:1337/")
            req.Proxy = New WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888)
            wr.SendRequest(req, 30000)
        Next
        mre.WaitOne()
    End Sub

End Class

Imports System.Net

Public Class RequestState

    Private bufferSize As Integer = 1024

    Public Property Request As HttpWebRequest
    Public Property Response As HttpWebResponse
    Public Property ResponseBody As String
    Public Property ResponseStream As IO.Stream
    Public Property ResponseData As Text.StringBuilder
    Public Property ReadBuffer As Byte()

    Public Sub New()
        ReadBuffer = New Byte(bufferSize) {}
        ResponseData = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    End Sub

End Class

Imports System.Net

Public Class WebRequester

    'Adapted from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

    Private mre As New Threading.ManualResetEvent(False)

    Public Event ResponseReceived(reqState As RequestState)
    Public Event ExceptionRaised(ex As Exception)

    Public Sub SendRequest(req As HttpWebRequest, timeOut As Integer)
        Try
            Dim reqState As New RequestState
            reqState.Request = req
            Dim result As IAsyncResult = reqState.Request.BeginGetResponse(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf RespCallback), reqState)
            Threading.ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(result.AsyncWaitHandle, New Threading.WaitOrTimerCallback(AddressOf TimeoutCallback), reqState.Request, timeOut, True)
            mre.WaitOne()
            reqState.Response.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            RaiseEvent ExceptionRaised(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub RespCallback(asyncResult As IAsyncResult)
        Try
            Dim reqState As RequestState = asyncResult.AsyncState
            reqState.Response = reqState.Request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult)
            reqState.ResponseStream = reqState.Response.GetResponseStream
            reqState.ResponseStream.BeginRead(reqState.ReadBuffer, 0, 1024, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReadCallback), reqState)
        Catch ex As Exception
            RaiseEvent ExceptionRaised(ex)
        End Try
        mre.Set()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReadCallback(asyncResult As IAsyncResult)
        Try
            Dim reqState As RequestState = asyncResult.AsyncState
            'Read the buffer, if there is more data, recursively call responseStream.BeginRead
            Dim read As Integer = reqState.ResponseStream.EndRead(asyncResult)
            If read > 0 Then
                reqState.ResponseData.Append(Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(reqState.ReadBuffer, 0, read))
                Dim ar As IAsyncResult = reqState.ResponseStream.BeginRead(reqState.ReadBuffer, 0, 1024, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReadCallback), reqState)
                Return
            Else
                'Request complete!
                reqState.ResponseBody = reqState.ResponseData.ToString
                reqState.ResponseStream.Close()
                reqState.ResponseStream.Dispose()
                RaiseEvent ResponseReceived(reqState)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            RaiseEvent ExceptionRaised(ex)
        End Try
        mre.Set()
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub TimeoutCallback(state As Object, timedOut As Boolean)
        If timedOut Then
            Dim request As HttpWebRequest = state

            If Not (request Is Nothing) Then
                request.Abort()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub 'TimeoutCallback

End Class
```

In response to the possible dupe question,  except for the fact that we were both reusing HttpWebRequest objects, our situations seem to be different enough to warrant a new question. Technically I am not even asking if a HttpWebRequest can be reused, I am really asking why when I do, I receive the exception I posted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Am I able to reuse a HttpWebRequest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179626/am-i-able-to-reuse-a-httpwebrequest)

Comment: @GSerg The OP in that question was having problems with time outs, mine is an issue with the connection being closed unexpectedly.   Except for the fact that we were both reusing HttpWebRequest objects, our situations seem to be different enough to warrant a new question.  Technically I am not even asking if a HttpWebRequest can be reused, I am really asking why when I do, I receive the exception I posted.  Thanks though!  BTW, I added the HttpWebResponse.Close call to my code at the end of each request, as that SO question you linked suggested in the answer and the exception persists.