# HTTP webrequest for making persistent connection

Tags: c#

How do I make the second request within that same connection?

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("String.url");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
String result = reader.ReadToEnd();

stream.Dispose();
reader.Dispose();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179626/am-i-able-to-reuse-a-httpwebrequest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Am I able to reuse a HttpWebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179626/am-i-able-to-reuse-a-httpwebrequest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP web request makes a persistent connection..... u can use both "GET" or"POST"
you can increase a connection how much u want(eg 3 to 20 or 50 ...etc)

```
           string webpageContent = "";
           byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("value");
           HttpWebRequest webRequest (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
           webRequest.Method = "POST";
           webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
           webRequest.Timeout = 120000;
           System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 3;
           webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
           webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
           using (Stream webpageStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
           {
               webpageStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
           }
           using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
           {
               using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
               {
                   webpageContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
               }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `KeepAlive` property on `HttpWebRequest` is used to persist connections. It defaults to `true`.

Here's the doc with more details:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive(v=vs.110).aspx